# Why isn't my HTML button registering a click?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button, event-handling

I'm working on submitting forms and showing content based on a chosen response. Right now I'm just trying to get the buttons to work so it can go from one question to a display with the correct answer and then on to the next question.
index.js

```
function startQuiz() {
    $('#startButton').click(function(event){
        console.log("Keep Going");
        renderQuestion();
    }
    );
}
let questionNumber= 0

function renderQuestion() {
    console.log("hello");
    let questions = STORE.questions[questionNumber];
    const questionTemplate = $( `
    <div class="container" align="center">
        ${questions.image}
          <p>${questions.questionText}<br></p>
          <form method="post" onsubmit="return nextQuestion()">
              <input type="radio" name="choice">${questions.responses[0]}<br>
              <input type="radio" name="choice">${questions.responses[1]}<br>
              <input type="radio" name="choice">${questions.responses[2]}<br>
              <input type="radio" name="choice">${questions.responses[3]}<br>
              <button input type="submit" id="choose" value="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
      </div>`);
      $("main").html(questionTemplate);
}

function checkAnswer() {
$("main").on("click","#choose",function(event){
    let questions = STORE.questions[questionNumber];
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("clicked");
    const correctResponse = $(`
    <div class="container" align="center">
    ${questions.image}
    <h4>${questions.answer}</h4>
    <p>Correct!<p>
    <button input type="submit id="next" value="submit">Next</button>
    </div>`);
    $("main").html(correctResponse);
})
}

function nextQuestion(){
$("main").on("click","#next",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Don't turn back");
    questionNumber= questionNumber +1;
    renderQuestion();
})}

$(checkAnswer)
$(startQuiz)
```

I've created a `console.log()` so I can see when the button is pressed but it doesn't come up. On the other hand it isn't refreshing the page, it just seems like it's not doing anything.

index.html

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Herbal Medicine: Adaptogens</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="questions" href="store.html">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
  <script src="store.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Herbal Medicine: Adaptogens</h1>
  <main>
    <div class="container" class="firstLetter">
      <p>Adaptogens are a category of healing herbs that have a number of beneficial qualities for the human body. They
        are characterized by their ability to perform well with other medications and supplements, they can build up in
        the system without negative effects, and they help the body adapt to stress on many levels. <br> 
        Stress can be emotional, physical and mental and the various adaptogens tend to apply their healing qualities to those areas
        of the body that most need support.<br>
        Herbal medicine has been cataloged throughout the ages, with physical records uncovered as early as 1500 BCE.
        Most prescription medications have been derived from plants, and their latin or botanical names will indicate
        such.<br>
        Test your knowledge and learn a thing or two about healing herbs!<br>
      </p>
      <button id="startButton">Start</button>
      <br> <h12>The statements in this quiz are not intended to diagnose or treat any conditions. When in doubt ask a pro!</h12>
    </div>
      </main>

</body>

</html>
```

store.js

```
const STORE = {
    questions: [ {
        image: `<div class="image"> <img src="nettles.svg", alt="mystery plant illustration"> </div>`,
            questionText: "Which plant provides the most minerals and nutrients.",
            responses: [
                "Licorice <i>Glycyrrhiza glabra</i>",
                "Jiagulon <i>Gynostemma pentaphyllum</i>",
                "Lemon Balm <i>Melissa Officianlis</i>",
                "Nettles <i>Urtica dioica</i>"
            ],
            answer: "Nettles <i>Urtica dioica</i>"
        },
        {
            questionText: "Which Plant is known for lowering  high cholesterol, high blood pressure, and improving heart function as well as improving memory, and preventing hair loss?",
            responses: [
                "Jiagulon <i>Gynostemma pentaphyllum</i>",
                "Licorice <i>Glycyrrhiza glabra</i>",
                "Nettles <i>Urtica dioica</i>",
                "Lemon Balm <i>Melissa Officianlis</i>"
            ],
            answer: "Jiagulon <i>Gynostemma pentaphyllum</i>"
        }
]
}
```

Comment: It would help if you could provide the HTML.

Comment: Can you share the html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several smaller issues, including a typo:

1. button cannot have "input" attribute
2. In checkAnswer(), you have an unclosed " after submit: type="submit id="next"

The main problem is that you have click eventListener on the #choose button as well as an onsubmit function on the form. Fix these issues above, remove the onsubmit and add nextQuestion() to the bottom of checkAnswer() and it should work fine. The rest of your code is OK.

Comment: so simple! much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> In index.js try this,

```
function checkAnswer() {
$("main").on("click","#choose",function(event){
    let questions = STORE.questions[questionNumber];
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("clicked");
    const correctResponse = $(`
    <div class="container" align="center">
        ${questions.image}
    <h4>${questions.answer}</h4>
    <p>Correct!<p>
    <button input type="submit" id="next" value="submit">Next</button>
    </div>`);
    $("main").html(correctResponse);
    // for registering #next id event
    nextQuestion();
})
```

}

> //Explaination:

function nextQuestion() is registring your #next click event, In DOM #next id will be present after $("main").html(correctResponse); line.
so nextQuestion() should be call when #next id will placed in DOM successfully.